# How do sound vortex cannons work

Tags: pressure, acoustics, vortex

How does a sound vortex cannon amplify pressure waves? Does it work by compression, so that they are more focused, or in some other way?

Comment: Related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IyAyd4WnvhU . There is no "amplification" going on - just transmission of the pressure over distance.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no amplification taking place in the formation of a vortex ring. In fact there is a significant amount of energy loss to form the ring.

A vortex ring is a special soliton wave that captures a fixed amount of energy in as it is formed. It can carry this energy over a long distance with minor dissipation and then transfer the energy to the target it strikes.

So it's really the *stable nature* of the vortex ring, its structure, that makes it a practical choice as a 'projectile'. But to do significant 'damage' to a target takes a significant amount of generating energy from the cannon in which it is formed.